# if page has selector - Capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to implement a simple piece of logic that says if element exists on page do something`

The issue I am facing is that if the element doesn't exist then the `find` method provided returns an exception and will fail my test.

```
(Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

so for example I want to do something like:

```
if page.find(".element")
  do something
end
```

If the element doesn't exist then the test should just carry on as normal.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the `begin/rescue` sctructure: http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/003-The_Universe_between_begin_and_end.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using something like this:

```
if page.has_css?('selector')
  do something
end
```

This method is described [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_css%3F-instance_method)

Comment: arghhh! i was trying this but couldnt get it working for whatever reason, just revisited it and it works..

Comment: This certainly is a better way to do it.